# Is there a tool that generates "Linear Gradient" for other browsers?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients, autoprefixer

I have this linear gradient for mozilla:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #bbb, #ccc 30%, #ccc 70%, #bbb);
```

is there a tool that generates this linear gradient but for other browser ? (webkit, IE, opera ecc) ??

Thanks a lot and sorry fory my english :)

Comment: What browsers do you care about that don't support the non-prefixed form? For that matter, why are you using -moz-? Do you have a lot of people using (the ancient) Firefox 15 and earlier?

Comment: remove the prefix and then see if you want to support old browsers

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Yes, there is (e.g. [Gradient CSS Generator from CSSmatic](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator), found with one quick Google search), but remember that stackoverflow isn't here to recommend programs

Comment: @GCyrillus i remove the prefix but doesn't work (i have firefox 44.0.2)

Comment: without prefix, it can be written:`background-image: linear-gradient(#bbb, #ccc 30%, #ccc 70%, #bbb);`

Answer (score 2):

You could this http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. This generates gradient for almost all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many of them online that you can quickly find. Here's one:

http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator

For similar questions of this type, there is a brand new service recently launched called `Google` where you can enter what you're looking for into a search box and it'll find and display relevant results. I typed 'linear gradient css3' for this answer.

Comment: Please don't up vote this -- it was a sarcastic response to a question that shouldn't have been asked.